# .Any() with Nullables - Returns False When I Expect True

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, nullable

I have a view model with a nullable int...

```
public ObjectViewModel (){
    public int? Total
}
```

... and there are several rows in my DB where the total is *null*.

Despite that, this always returns *false*:

```
bool exists = repo.AllRows() // renamed this for clarity; returns IQueryable
                  .Any(r => r.Total == vm.Total); // I know r.Total and vm.Total
                                                  // are both null
```

But the following returns *true* (as expected):

```
bool exists = repo.All().Any(r => r.Total == null);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: if vm is null, you'll get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: From where do you get vm and what value has it? From the results I would expect that it has a value which does not exist in your result set.

Comment: What is the purpose of calling `All` before `Any`?

Comment: regarding vm, eventhought you havent stated you are doing this in loop be carefull if you do so: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: What's the predicate in `All`? As far as I know it can't be called without one.

Comment: `All` also returns a boolean so I suspect it wasn't meant to be in the example.

Comment: I have renamed All() in the example to be clearer. It's a repo method, not the All() extension.  Mea Culpa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Assuming you meant "vm.Total is null" and that `All()` was a typo...*

I think your problem is the way this is translated into SQL:

- the first query gets translated as a WHERE clause with `r.Total = @param1`
- the second query gets translated as a WHERE clause using `IS NULL`

[MSDN has a good description on NULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196106%28SQL.80%29.aspx):

> A value of NULL indicates the value is
>   unknown. A value of NULL is different
>   from an empty or zero value. No two
>   null values are equal. Comparisons
>   between two null values, or between a
>   NULL and any other value, return
>   unknown because the value of each NULL
>   is unknown.

This means that you cannot use Comparison operators in SQL - and hence also you can't in Linq to sql either.

Some ways around this are:

- to test for null in vm.Total before you choose which form of query to use.
- to use `Object.Equals` for the comparison - see this blog post for more info on this - http://www.brentlamborn.com/post/LINQ-to-SQL-Null-check-in-Where-Clause.aspx

Comment: +1, this is surely an example of a mismatch in C# and SQL. I believe you can use the null coalescing operator (??) in C# to have LINQ use ISNULL(foo, 0) instead. As for the `All()` call, not only doesn't he need it but it won't compile. I suspect it was a mistake.

Comment: Added link to blog post - http://www.brentlamborn.com/post/LINQ-to-SQL-Null-check-in-Where-Clause.aspx

Comment: The .All() confusion arises from the fact that I have an All() method in my repository that returns the result of `from m in context select m`.  I am not referring to the .All() extension method.  It compiles just fine.  :-)

Comment: @ScottSEA doesn't that seem like a bad idea?

Comment: @Josh - yep, refactoring as we speak.  <sigh> :-)

Comment: This turned out to be the solution to the problem - I didn't realize that `null == null` will always return false.

Answer (score 2):

Josh's answer seems the most accurate to me. Simply use the null coalescing operator :

```
bool exists = repo.AllRows().Any(r => r.Total ?? 0 == vm.Total ?? 0);
```

... and you won't have a kind of "WHERE NULL = NULL" anymore, but a "WHERE 0 = 0" which is okay.

Answer (score 0):

As Bala R says, if vm is null so you'll not be able to access to `Total` property and it must throw NullReferenceException.

Your query should be:

```
bool exists = repo.Any(r => r.Total == null);
```

`exists` will be true if there is a record at least with `null` in `Total` property.

Answer (score 0):

The `Any` method returns true if any of the items in your collection meet the condition specified by the lambda. So none of the items in `repo` have a Total which equals `vm.Total` however there are items which are null so the second returns true.

To verify, thrown a little debug code in there,

```
Console.WriteLine("vm.Total=" + vm.Total.ToString());
foreach (var r in repo)
    Console.WriteLine("r.Total=" r.Total == null ? "null" : r.Total.ToString());
```

And take a look at the items, you should not see `r.Total` which is equal to `vm.Total` and you will see at least one `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should give an exception but either way you could try:

```
Any(r => r.Total == vm==null ? null : vm.Total)
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, but don't you need some parenthesis in there?  `Any(r => r.Total == (vm==null) ? null: vm.Total)`

Comment: I didn't actually run the code but I believe that you don't. Look up the ternary operator or the conditional operator as C# likes to call it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=VS.100).aspx